# How to start subscription when another publisher is ready with project Reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Using Reactor, I have a `Mono` and a `Flux`, the `Mono` does some polling on a channel and the `Flux` publishes on this channel. In a test, I would like the `Flux` to start publishing data only when the `Mono` is effectively polling. Since the polling on the `Mono` does not start as soon as it is subscribed on, I have been using a fixed `delaySubscription` before starting the publishing:

```
Mono<...> polling;
Flux<...> dataPublisher;
polling
     .zipWith(dataPublisher.collectList().delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
     .block()
```

This way is "working" but is a bit flaky, since the publishing happens at a a point in which it is possible that the polling `Mono` is not yet ready to poll.

I have tried to find another less flaky way to test this, but haven't find it yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use [Mono.thenMany](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#thenMany-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for a Sink. Basically it is a thing you can trigger which you can then use to start a new mono(single trigger)/flux(multiple triggers) with.
A simplified example:

```
    @Test
    public void pollAndPublish() {
        //create a sink to trigger
        Sinks.One<Boolean> sink = Sinks.one();
        //start the polling mono, I'm asusming polling starts somewhere after some time, I made it 2 seconds
        Mono<String> polling = Mono.just("I start polling after some time")
                                   .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                                   .map(it -> "I'm polling")
                                   .doOnNext(it -> sink.tryEmitValue(true))
                                   .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                                   .map(it -> "I'm done polling");

        //turn the trigger into a new mono and map it to your publisher flux
        Flux<String> dataPublisher = sink.asMono()
                                         .flatMapMany(it -> Flux.just("elements", "to", "publish")
                                                                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)));

        //start the polling pipeline
        polling.subscribe();

        //start the publisher pipeline
        StepVerifier.create(dataPublisher)
                    .expectNext("elements")
                    .expectNext("to")
                    .expectNext("publish")
                    .verifyComplete();
    }
```